# Is minimizing $E[f(N_x)]$ equivalent to minimizing $f(x)$?

Tags: probability

> Let $N_x\sim \mathcal N(x,\sigma^2)$. Let $f(x)$ be an analytic function with a unique minimum. Additionally assume that $E[f(N_x)]$ has a unique minimum over $x$. Does $$\arg\min_Xf(x)=\arg \min E[f(N_x)]$$

This seems false but I would like a counterexample. I'm assuming it's false because $f(x)$ can have a minimum that's not "symmetric", in which case moving the $x$ a bit might make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not the simplest counter example, but it will be sufficed for your purpose.

Let $f(x) = 2x^4 - x$ with the unique minimum at $x = 1/2$.

Since $N_x \stackrel {d} {=} x + \sigma Z $ where $Z$ is the standard normal,

$$ \begin{align} g(x) &\triangleq E[f(N_x)] \\
&= E[2(x + \sigma Z)^4 - (x + \sigma Z)] \\
&= 2x^4 + 8\sigma x^3E[Z] + 12\sigma^2x^2E[Z^2]+8\sigma^3xE[Z^3]+2\sigma^4E[Z^4]-x-\sigma E[Z] \\
&= 2x^4+12\sigma^2x^2 - x + 6\sigma^4
\end{align} $$

So in general it is not minimize at $x = 1/2$.

E.g. When $\sigma = 1$,

$g(1/2) = 69/8 > 8$ whereas $g(0) = 6 < g(1/2)$